# Bind multiple times jStepper to input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jStepper plugin to my numeric input values. I need to change range of valid digits depend on what value of select input is chosed. I have sample demo on http://jsfiddle.net/vqjb2/1/.

```
<input type="text" id="testId" />

<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>

</select>

$("#testId").jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: 20, minLength: 1, defaultValue: 0 });

$("#select").on("change", function(event) {

    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == 1) {
         $("#testId").jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: 20, minLength: 1, defaultValue: 0 });
    }
    else if (val == 2) {
         $("#testId").jStepper({ minValue: 0, maxValue: 5, minLength: 1, defaultValue: 0 });
    }
});
```

When page is loaded it works fine because max value is 20. Then when I change value of drop down to "2" max value is 5 and it works fine too, but when I change it to "1" again it still have max value of 5 instead of `20`.

Comment: your jsfiddle throws this error in the console TypeError: $(...).jStepper is not a function

Comment: It doesn't look like the plugin allows you to change the settings for an element after it's been initialized.

Comment: Yes and not, when page is loaded it have 20 as max, then I can change max to 5, but then I can't change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.5.0 of the plugin (published about 3 months ago) you can change the options after the plugin has been initialized.

What you have tried so far is to rebind the plugin to the text field and that is not supported.

What you want to do is call something like this inside your change event handler:

```
$('#testId').jStepper('option', 'maxValue', 20);
```

and

```
$('#testId').jStepper('option', 'maxValue', 5);
```

Check out the documentation at http://jstepper.emkay.dk/